# Crackling while playing games and watching youtube

Tags: audio, youtube, gaming

recently I've been playing games and been watching YouTube at the same time, and I've started to notice that there is a weird crackling noise when I play and I lag a lot does anyone know why?

This is my computer: https://www.msi.com/Laptop/GP72-2QE-Leopard-Pro.html#hero-overview

I've been playing Rainbow Six Siege 
and watching YouTube at 480p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it's because of you HDD cannot handle the load. A 5400rmp HDD just can't handle a lot of today's content. Try running the game from the SSD, should make a big difference and try playing the youtube video from Opera. It handles multitasking and resource allocation better. Make sure your video drivers are up to date (or are a good stable version).

Comment: hey man thanks for the explanation but I'd like to know your thought process, why is it not the RAM (for temp mem) or GPU (for graphic loads and 'probably' audio as well) or even MOBO (audio quality) but the HDD? it just seems to me that the hard disk is the least possible cause here since it only provides static mem?

Comment: Because HDDs did not evolve like the other components did. GPUs are dozes of times faster of that they used to be ~15 years ago, CPUs are a few times faster and the HDDs are barely double to triple the speed. What actually kills the HDDs are the very large number of files post-Vista Windows operating systems have.